# Count com HQL JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

## Problema

Como faço para receber a quantidade de registro de uma tabela do banco de dados?

```
public Integer quantidadeRegistros() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Categoria cat");
        return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

## Erro

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at erp.dao.CategoriaDao.quantidadeRegistros(CategoriaDao.java:100)
    at erp.dao.CategoriaDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d3c7f86.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at erp.dao.CategoriaDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$252f3a07.quantidadeRegistros(<generated>)
    at erp.service.CategoriaService.quantidadeRegistros(CategoriaService.java:95)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mude o `*` por `cat` na sua query:

```
public Integer quantidadeRegistros() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(cat) FROM Categoria cat");
        return (Integer) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

A regra para consultas jpql é:

```
SELECT COUNT(entidade) FROM Entidade entidade
```

Dessa forma como você está utilizando deveria ser uma NativeQuery com SQL nativo:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Categoria").getSingleResult();
```

---

#### Atualização:

Seu problema está no cast também, troque `Integer` por `Long`:

```
public Long quantidadeRegistros() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(cat) FROM Categoria cat");
        return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Ou use o retorno direto para `Integer`, fazendo o cast de `Long` para `Integer`:

```
public Integer quantidadeRegistros() {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(cat) FROM Categoria cat");
        return query.getSingleResult() != null ? 
               Integer.parseInt(query.getSingleResult().toString()) : 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Se quise fazer o cast de `Long` para `int` no seu `ManagedBean` use:

```
Integer quantidadeRegistros = valorLong != null ? valorLong.intValue() : null;
```

Referência:

- https://www.guj.com.br/t/jpa-como-usar-count/289701

Comment: Aconteceu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Verifique a atualização que coloquei

Comment: Porque que teve que fazer o cast para um tipo Long?

Comment: Pois a quantidade de registros é retornada em Long por padrão. Há casos em que um Integer pode não aguentar a quantidade de registros de uma tabela com bilhões de registos.

Comment: Isso foi definido nos padões do Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0, mais específicamente na cláusula 4.8.4 que define: COUNT returns Long. Mais informações no link da especifícação (em inglês):
 https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/